# Loop through array of objs, check if value exists, return opposite value / Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have challenge to create a simple translator and I'm stuck. I have a **dictionary.js** which has pairs of words in en/fr, looks like this:

```
const dictionary = [{en:'dog', fr:'chien'}, {en:'cat', fr:'chat'}];
```

I need a function that will take user input, check if this word is in the dictionary, if yes = return the opposite value. eg:

```
wordTranslator = (word) => {};

wordTranslator('dog'); // expected output 'chien'
```

I started with looping through the array:

```
for(word.value in dictionary)
```

I assume the function finds 'dog' in dictionary at certain index, how to make it return it's sibling?

Thank you for any help, I'm still learning ;)

Comment: please share the code you have written.!!

Comment: You're close: 
`for (entry in dictionary)`
`  if (entry.en === word)`
`    return entry.fr`

Comment: This is why we use property files (or structure) for translation (or Internationalization) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties That way, you have a key pointing to the actual words. You can use something like `{'animal.cat': {'fr': 'chat', 'en': 'cat'}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the below. Note I also added the ability to say which output type you want. You could also pass in the `from` as well.

```
const wordTranslator = (word, to) => {
    const from = to === 'en' ? 'fr' : 'en';
    const item = dictionary.find(item => item[from] === word);
    return item ? item[to] : '';
};
```

Comment: the word is in strings? it should be `word`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search for the first match.

This will return an empty string if the word is not find.

```js
const dictionary = [
  {en: 'dog',fr: 'chien'}, 
  {en: 'cat',fr: 'chat'}
];

wordTranslator = (word) => (dictionary.find(o => o.en === word) || {fr: ""}).fr;

console.log(wordTranslator('dog'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dictionary = [{en:'dog', fr:'chien'}, {en:'cat', fr:'chat'}];

wordTranslator = (word) => dictionary.find(item => item.en === word).fr;

console.log(wordTranslator('dog'))
```

Comment: This works only when translating english to french, not the other way around. OP is asking for getting the *opposite* value

Answer (score 0):

use [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to look for the word in `en`, if found, return the `fr` word, else look for the word in `fr` and return the `en`

```js
const dictionary = [{
  en: 'dog',
  fr: 'chien'
}, {
  en: 'cat',
  fr: 'chat'
}];

const wordTranslator = (word) => {
  let x = dictionary.find(e => e.en === word)
  if (x) return x.fr
  else return dictionary.find(e => e.fr === word).en
};

const word1 = wordTranslator('dog')
const word2 = wordTranslator('chat')

console.log(word1)
console.log(word2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = [{en:'dog', fr:'chien'}, {en:'cat', fr:'chat'}]

const findItem = (word) => (
  input.find(item => (item.fr === word || item.en === word))
)

const findTranslation = (word) => {
  const item = findItem(word);
  return item.fr === word ? item.en : item.fr
}

// Use only findTranslation:
console.log(findTranslation('dog')) // 'chien'
console.log(findTranslation('chat')) // 'cat'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wat to add another parameter to pass to the function…
… I'll probably do something like the below.

See comments in my snippet:

```js
const dictionary = [
  {en: 'dog', fr: 'chien'}, 
  {en: 'cat', fr: 'chat'}
];

wordTranslator = (word) => {
  var result = dictionary.find(elm => elm.en === word);
  if (result) return result.fr;
    result = dictionary.find(elm => elm.fr === word);
  if (result) return result.en;
  return '--- Not found ---'; // Customizable
};

// EN -> FR
console.log(wordTranslator('dog'));
console.log(wordTranslator('cat'));
console.log(wordTranslator('bird'));

// FR -> EN
console.log(wordTranslator('chien'));
console.log(wordTranslator('chat'));
console.log(wordTranslator('oiseau'));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is better for create a dictionary kind of structure at once looping through your array and use it for your all searches.

```
var cloneDictionary = {};
dictionary.forEach(ele => {
cloneDictionary[ele['en']] = ele.fr
})
wordTranslator = ((word) => cloneDictionary[word]);
```